# Vagrant, Chef-solo and Java cookbook: Error executing action `install` on resource 'java_ark[jdk]'

Tags: java, chef-infra, vagrant

I've setup a Vagrant box with precise64 and am trying to install Oracle Java 7 using The Java Cookbook (http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/java) but I get error:

```
Error executing action `install` on resource 'java_ark[jdk]'
```

I run *Vagrant up* and get the following output in Terminal:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Importing base box 'precise64'...
[default] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
[default] Setting the name of the VM...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] -- 80 => 8080 (adapter 1)
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
[default] Machine booted and ready!
[default] The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
your host and reload your VM.

Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
VirtualBox Version: 4.3
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- /vagrant
[default] -- /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-2/roles
[default] -- /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks
[default] Running provisioner: chef_solo...
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
Running chef-solo...
stdin: is not a tty
[2014-01-09T09:25:53+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 10.14.2 ***
[2014-01-09T09:25:55+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["role[myrecipes]"] from JSON
[2014-01-09T09:25:55+00:00] INFO: Run List is [role[myrecipes]]
[2014-01-09T09:25:55+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [java]
[2014-01-09T09:25:55+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for precise64
[2014-01-09T09:25:55+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2014-01-09T09:25:55+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2014-01-09T09:25:56+00:00] INFO: ruby_block[set-env-java-home] called
[2014-01-09T09:25:56+00:00] INFO: file[/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh] mode changed to 755
[2014-01-09T09:25:56+00:00] INFO: file[/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh] created file /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
[2014-01-09T09:25:56+00:00] INFO: Adding jdk to /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45

================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'java_ark[jdk]'
================================================================================

NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `headers' for Chef::Resource::RemoteFile

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/java/providers/ark.rb:70:in `download_direct_from_oracle'
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/java/providers/ark.rb:67:in `download_direct_from_oracle'
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/java/providers/ark.rb:108:in `class_from_file'

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/java/recipes/oracle.rb

 46: 
 47: java_ark "jdk" do
 48:   url tarball_url
 49:   checksum tarball_checksum
 50:   app_home java_home
 51:   bin_cmds bin_cmds
 52:   alternatives_priority 1062
 53:   action :install
 54: end
 55: 

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/java/recipes/oracle.rb:47:in `from_file'

java_ark("jdk") do
  app_home "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64"
  checksum "bea330fcbcff77d31878f21753e09b30"
  retry_delay 2
  owner "root"
  default true
  url "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u45-b18/jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz"
  retries 0
  alternatives_priority 1062
  recipe_name "oracle"
  action [:install]
  bin_cmds ["appletviewer", "apt", "ControlPanel", "extcheck", "idlj", "jar", "jarsigner", "java", "javac", "javadoc", "javafxpackager", "javah", "javap", "javaws", "jcmd", "jconsole", "jcontrol", "jdb", "jhat", "jinfo", "jmap", "jps", "jrunscript", "jsadebugd", "jstack", "jstat", "jstatd", "jvisualvm", "keytool", "native2ascii", "orbd", "pack200", "policytool", "rmic", "rmid", "rmiregistry", "schemagen", "serialver", "servertool", "tnameserv", "unpack200", "wsgen", "wsimport", "xjc"]
  cookbook_name :java
  supports {:exception=>true, :report=>true}
end

[2014-01-09T09:25:56+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-01-09T09:25:56+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-01-09T09:25:56+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-01-09T09:25:56+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: java_ark[jdk] (java::oracle line 47) had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `headers' for Chef::Resource::RemoteFile
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

**My Vagrantfile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "precise64"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Chef-solo
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["site-cookbooks", "cookbooks"]
    chef.roles_path = "roles"
    chef.add_role "myrecipes"
  end

end
```

**roles/myrecipes.rb**

```
name "myrecipes"

default_attributes(
    "java" => {
        "install_flavor" => "oracle",
        "jdk_version" => 7,
        "oracle" => {
                "accept_oracle_download_terms" => true
        }
    }
)

run_list(
    "recipe[apt]",
    "recipe[openssl]",
    "recipe[java]"
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is a mismatch between the version of Chef you are using (10.14.2) and the `java` cookbook.

The implementation of the `java_ark` resource provider on the cookbook is attempting to use the `header` method of the Chef `remote_file` resource when it downloads the Oracle installer.  The problem is that the `header` method was only implemented on the `remote_file` resource in Chef 11.6.0 (by my reading of the chef source code on Github).

The solution is to either upgrade to the latest version of Chef, or use an older version of the `java` cookbook that works with Chef 10.x.  (The latter is probably a bad idea ... unless you are prepared to manually set the latest Oracle download URL and checksum in the relevant attributes ...)

Comment: That fixed the issue. I now use Omnibus to ensure Chef runs the latest version everytime I 'Vagrant up'. Thanks

Comment: I'm running with `test-kitchen` that I installed on April-21-2014. Any advice on how to deal with this same error - `Error executing action `install` on resource 'java_ark[jdk]`

Comment: @KevinMeredith - Advice - read the rest of the diagnostics.  They will give you clues as to what actually went wrong.